# Closing a question for lack of clarity or focus or objectivity should require elaboration from the closer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close, close-dialog

I see a lot of questions about, "Why was this issue closed for lack of clarity/focus/opinion-based?" I'd like to propose something that could preemptively answer these questions before they're even asked.

I want to preface this by saying I'm aware that I am proposing something extremely specific and detailed, but I'm doing it as food for thought. I'm not tied to the specifics; I just think it'll help others visualize my mental model and provide fodder for a discussion that leads to the best possible solution.

With that out of the way, let's look at the current UI for closing a question:

[image]

Here's the change I'm proposing: if you select "Needs details or clarity" or "Needs more focus" or "Opinion-based", you must populate a text field that requires elaboration *relating to the specifics of the question*.

For example, if you are closing a question for, "Needs details or clarity," the closer might write, "I can't tell if this question is asking about apples or oranges. Please clarify."

If you are closing a question for, "Needs more focus," the closer might write, "This asks how to tell when apples and oranges are ripe. It should focus on one or the other."

And if you are closing a question for, "Opinion-based," the closer might write, "Asking if apples taste better than oranges is subjective."

When the next person votes to close the same question for the same reason, the UI would look similar to closing a question for, "A community-specific reason":

[image]

But in this case, the list of radio buttons will be populated with the text written by previous closer(s). If you disagree with the specifics written by the previous closer(s), the last radio button will be a text field, allowing you to add your own reason to the list.

Ultimately, I think this could reduce the number of, "Why was this closed?" questions/comments, improve question quality, make these interactions less intimidating for new contributors, and increase the sense of "fairness" when one's question is closed.

Comment: Actually, on Meta downvotes indicate disagreement; they're not a reflection of question quality.

Comment: @TylerH oh! That's fine then. Maybe the tooltip should say that, but that's a topic for another meta question :)

Comment: I tend to agree in principle, but, i'd prefer it be more of a nudge, similar to the popup users get when they cast a downvote on an answer prior to having 2k rep... and similarly make said popup show up less often as your experience with the site increases. If there *is* something of value the closer can suggest via a comment, they can probably do a better job of it using comments directly rather than selecting a canned reason or entering text into a small text input.

Comment: Of course, none of this works once the votes are occurring in review instead, but the original voter had the ability to leave a comment, and you can leave comments in review.

Comment: “… you must populate a text field that requires elaboration relating to the specifics of the question.” - I’ll just submit “needs more focus as outlined in the help center”, which of course serves no purpose, and why should I as a close voter justify my close vote when the question’s author should have put more effort into their question to insure their question didn’t have to be closed for requiring more detail? **Besides you can already do what you are suggesting today.** Nobody does this because questions authors are extremely toxic and serial downvote you.

Comment: I agree about the tooltip, but it's been [`status-declined` since way before I joined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75049/1274780).

Comment: I'm curious... how many close votes did you cast using those options, and how many times did you post an explanatory comment?

Comment: Requiring explanations may also be problematic while staying kind. If the explanation is "your question is a completely incomprehensible mess, I'm not even sure it qualifies as English since those words don't make sense in that order", it might just be better to leave that unspoken.

Comment: @ErikA You've got to be cruel to be kind.

Comment: @DanMašek I believe I've gone down both routes in the past. Regardless, let's assume I've never elaborated on any question I've closed. Let's go even further. Assume I've closed more questions than anyone else on the site. What bearing does that have on the proposal?

Answer (score 24):

Honestly?  I don't see that many questions about it.  Some people have been asking them more on Meta, which is good, and we can handle it on Meta since it's a ***vanishingly small number of people*** who ask a question about why their question was closed compared to the number of people who have their questions closed.

Closing questions should be done as quickly as possible, because what we accomplish with question closure is several things intended to preserve question quality:

- Prevent bad subjective answers
- Prevent ping-pong answers, in which the asker insists on following up with more questions, which is emblematic of an incomplete question
- Prevent chameleon questions, in which someone could ask a question but it turns out to be something completely different that needs or warrants a different answer

Comments or justifications slow down this process, which devalues the platform.

I don't see any reason to worry about users in this scenario. The ones that care will come to Meta to receive either an explanation or a reversal.

Comment: Ah, that was a great response; it really helped me see things from a different perspective. Correct me if I'm wrong, but quality content seems to be the highest priority. My proposal had more to do with the user's experience (I don't mean UX, I mean things like engagement, etc.), and I understand why they at odds in this situation. I don't mean to imply any sort of judgment on the matter: I think focusing on the content is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @DanielKaplan:  UX isn't my obligation, my obligation is having correct answers and providing the best information I can to a user.  The information about why certain questions are simply not clear enough isn't on me to solve, it's on the company.  I'm not going to paper over it.

Answer (score 16):

Sometimes explanations for why a question post is unclear requires **much more effort** than an asker have devoted when creating a post. Example:

> If you want us to help you in solving the error in your case, then you need to provide code in your files `foo.c` and `foo.h`. If you ask how to avoid such situation at all, then your question is too broad, as there are too many steps which one could follow. Otherwise I don't understand what do you ask for.

I don't mind to leave detailed comments if a question is near the border and/or there is a great chance that the asker will fix the question. But if a question has a zero chance to be fixed, why should I spend my time for nothing?

Of course, I could leave a less detailed explanation, like

> I don't understand what the question asks about.

but .. this is the very text which is autogenerated for "Unclear" closing.

So, I don't find useful an idea to make **mandatory** explanations for a close vote.

Maybe, *recommendations* to provide such explanations (in the comments) would have a positive effect. But I am not sure which text should be used for such recommendations.

Comment: Yeah that's a perspective I hadn't considered. I was thinking more about the Closee's experience than the Closer's. As for your example, wouldn't it fall under the category of "A community-specific reason?" (See my second screenshot) Specifically, "Needs debugging details?" I'm not suggesting we remove those.

Comment: "As for your example, wouldn't it fall under the category of ..." - It could fall into **several categories** at once. There is a funny fact that some unclear questions could be read differently by different people, and **different readings** could lead to **different close reasons**: "Unclear", "Too broad", "Need debugging details", "Opinion-based". I remember that on meta I have described a real question with all such voting justified, but I have failed to find that post.